# gradle junit runs: how to pick tests from jar file

Tags: junit, gradle

We can run j[unit batchtest with tests picked from a jar file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619540/ant-junit-batchtest-from-a-jar)

```
<zipfileset src="tests-only.jar" includes="**/*Test.class"/>
```

This runs all matching tests picked from test-only.jar

How to do similar thing with gradle. The [testClassesDir](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:testClassesDir) only takes actual directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle doesn't have a built-in feature for running test classes contained in a Jar file. (Feel free to submit a feature request at http://forums.gradle.org .) What should work is unpacking the Jar (as a separate task) and then setting `testClassesDir` accordingly. Note that the test classes will also need to be present on the test task's `classpath` (but it might be good enough to use the Jar for this).

Comment: Done .  http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_junit_runs_pick_tests_test_class_names_from_jar_file?rfm=1

Answer (score 1):

See section [23.12.2](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#N12450) of the Gradle user namual. Note this information was found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516154/selecting-specific-tests-to-run-in-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by treating the jar-File as a zip-File in combination with a custom gradle Test task.

Lets assume the jar-File is on your project main runtimeClasspath and is named "tests-only.jar".

The followin snippet allows gradle to find the classes within the jar-File without actually extracting them:

```
task testOnlyTests(type: Test) {
  useJUnit()

  // the project runtimeClasspath should include all dependencies of the tests-only.jar file
  classpath = project.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

  testClassesDirs = project.sourceSets.main.output

  // find file tests-only.jar in dependencies or adjust the snippet to find it by other means
  File testJar = classpath.files.find { it.toString().contains("tests-only.jar") }
  testClassesDirs += zipTree(testJar)

  include("**/*Test.class")
}
```

The same should also be applicable directly to the "test" configuration of your project.